# Have anyone ever tried an artificial neural network with complex input and output values?

Tags: probability, neural-networks

Have anyone ever tried an artificial neural network with complex input and output values? An artificial neural network with input, hidden and output layers exchanging the complex numbers? And with complex activation function?
Can anyone count the benefits of such approach?

Answer (score 1):

A complex number is simply a pair of real numbers. A complex function is simply a pair of real functions of two variables. No big advance is likely.